# Certificate for multiple domains

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We have certificate for our all subdomains like

```
*.sitename.com
```

And one of white label client using it's website with

```
https://subdomain.whitelabel.com
```

And he is getting certificate error.

What is best practice to avoid this?

Comment: Get a certificate for subdomain.whitelabel.com or get a SAN/multi-domain certificate (fixed list of domains at issuance).  With the former consider you need a server that supports SNI or have multiple https endpoints/IPs.  whitelabel.sitename.com is the simplest solution.

Comment: Great, I will consider your suggestion. Thankyou.

Comment: I didn't get last line where you said buying "whitelabel.sitename.com", in our case white label client has his own domain and using our product on subdomain( subdomain.whitelabel.com), not subdomain of us (whitelabel.sitename.com).

Comment: I mean make him use something.yourdomain.com

Comment: He's already using his domain, what if he purchase *.whitelabel.com ?